# how can I send a string from angular 6 to springboot rest controller?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, http-post

I want to pass a single string from angular 6 using post to the springboot server controller, but it always fails with the httpErrorResponse 403, and error message is "forbidden", I am new to angular, hope someone can help me , thanks a lot. My java version is 10.
Following is my related code:

component.html:

```
<p-button label="Stop" styleClass="ui-button-danger" (onClick)="send()"></p- 
 button>
{{result}}
```

component.ts:

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedFile: string;
  selectedFile = "20180812";
  result: string;
  constructor(private cityService: CityService) {}

  send() {
  //pass a string  selectedFile
  this.cityService.send(this.selectedFile).subscribe(data=> this.result = 
  data);
  }
}
```

service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/internal/Observable";
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CityService {
  private testUrl = '//localhost:8080/sendString';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  send(s: string): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.post(this.testUrl, s, {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
          })
      });
   }
  }
```

controller.java:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
public class TestController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/sendString", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = 
                "text/plain")
public String pass(@RequestBody String test1) {
    System.out.println(test1);
    return test1;
}}
```

Error message on chrome browser:[The error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rF7X8.png)

securityConfig.java:

```
package com.predicine.sbproto.security;

import *;

@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity( securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

}
```

application.property:

```
#Security Configuration
spring.security.user.name=user
spring.security.user.password=user
spring.security.user.roles=USER
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you have a security configuration that needs some adjustment. It's usually in a Java-based config, frequently named WebSecurityConfig.java.
If you can post the contents of that file, we can probably help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, now I've added the securityConfig.java, please help me.

Comment: I add the following code in the securityCongif.java, then it works.
`http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());`
It is the spring security which forbidden the http POST method, GET method works fine.